# List of Shechita Halachot not found in YD 1 - 28?

Tags: slaughter-shochet-shecht

The bulk of hilchot shechita is found in Yoreh De'ah, Chapters 1 - 28. But there are other halachot connected to shechita scattered throughout the rest of Shulchan Aruch. Is there a resource that collects them all in one place.

The most obvious I can think of is Orach Chaim [498](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.498?lang=bi)-450 which discuss slaughtering, salting, and covering the blood on Yom Tov.

Some of them are more connected to the processing of the meat done after slaughter, such as [YD 67:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.67.4?lang=bi&with=About&lang2=en) and [YD 76:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.76.3?lang=bi&with=Siftei%20Kohen&lang2=en).

Obviously Shechita and Melicha are highly connected, but I'm mainly looking for things the Shochet needs to know and/or do pre-salting.

Comment: Have you considered using a later work like Simla Chadasha that is just a collection of slaughterers' laws?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Simla Chadasha is not a complete compendium of the laws of shechita. The author originally intended to write it on the whole shulchan aruch (he may have even done so), but the only parts we have are the ones he published in his Bechor Shor commentary on the Talmud. https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37876&st=&pgnum=7 . He does point to other chapters, but doesn't cover every law of shechita unless it applies to what is mentioned in chapters 1 - 28 (he also covers chapters 35-39)

Comment: Interesting one in hilchos treifos :  טוב להשקות הבהמה סמוך לשחיטה

Answer (score 1):

There is a Sefer from R' Yehoshua Hershkowitz called Torat HaOf. You can see the [first 40 pages for free on Otzar Hachachma, here](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/606059/p/3/t/8908303771234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c).

In this Sefer, the author collects all halachot that are applicable to the Kashrut of a bird, starting from when it is in the egg and through its lifecycle. It is a good overview of anything someone who wants to Shecht birds should know.

I haven't yet found a book like this that covers cattle.

---

From the title page:

> תורת העוף : אוצר הלכות העוף : סימני טהרה, מסורת,
> שחיטה, טריפות, מליחה, הלכות כשרות ביצי העוף : פסקים ותשובות מספרי השו"ת הקדמונים
> והאחרונים בשאלות שנתעוררו ונתחדשו בזמנינו בענין כשרות העוף